# How to add two columns of type timestamp and integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, timestamp

I am new with PostgreSQL and some of the functions are different from MYSQL. I am trying to add two columns in the table of which one is `timestamp without time zone` type and the other is `integer`.

The table looks like this:

Startime:    2015-02-09 19:00:00
Duration(seconds): 10

I want the output to give:

Star time: 2015-02-09 19:00:00

Duration: 10
Endtime : 2015-02-09 19:00:10

Comment: "Star time" or "start_time"?

Answer (score 4):

Convert your duration to an interval then add:

```
select
  start_time + ( duration_seconds * interval '1 second' )
from my_table;
```

You should use snake_case for Postgres identifiers, and don't use keywords as identifiers. Trust me.